# AHK in MS Excel (Cell Selection Issue With Script)

Tags: excel, autohotkey

I started a little script using CAPSLock key for navigation (This is only part of the code):

```
SetCapsLockState, AlwaysOff
CapsLock & i::
    if getkeystate("alt") = 0
            Send,{Up}
    else
            Send,+{Up}
return
CapsLock & l::
    if getkeystate("alt") = 0
            Send,{Right}
    else
 send, +{Right}
return
```

It works perfectly everywhere.. except in MS Excel!
When I select a range of cells the selection marquee is there but no cell reference is taken in the formula.
Ex: Summing C3:C10 turns into =sum()  no cells are actually selected in the formula.
if I keep trying up and down many times.. it shows, but never consistent.

Any idea how to fix this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from your shift key being released between the key presses.
Like for example try pressing keys like this in Excel and you'll see you're not actually selecting cells, you're just highlighting them:

```
Shift Down, Up Arrow, Shift Up
Shift Down, Up Arrow, Shift Up
Shift Down, Up Arrow, Shift Up
...
```

So you're going to have to keep shift pressed for the whole duration of your selection making process.
Here's what I could come up with:

```
CapsLock::Shift

#If, GetKeyState("CapsLock", "P")
*i::
    if (GetKeyState("Alt", "P"))
        SendInput, {Blind}{Alt Up}{Up}
    else
        SendInput, {Up}
return

*l::
    if (GetKeyState("Alt", "P"))
        SendInput, {Blind}{Alt Up}{Right}
    else
        SendInput, {Down}
return
#If
```

Or just like this to write it a lot cleaner with a ternary:

```
CapsLock::Shift

#If, GetKeyState("CapsLock", "P")
*i::SendInput, % GetKeyState("Alt", "P") ? "{Blind}{Alt Up}{Up}" : "{Up}" 
*l::SendInput, % GetKeyState("Alt", "P") ? "{Blind}{Alt Up}{Right}" : "{Right}"
#If
```

---

So what's happening?
First we use the simple remapping syntax<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm)</sup> to remap <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> to <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

Then we create context sensitive hotkeys for <kbd>I</kbd> and <kbd>L</kbd> with `#If`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_If.htm)</sup>.
The hotkeys are only triggered if the **physical** state of <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> is down.
We need the physical state, because the logical state (which is default) was remapped to shift.

The hotkeys are created with the `*` modifier<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#wildcard)</sup> so they fire even if <kbd>Shift</kbd> and/or <kbd>Alt</kbd> is held down.

I switched the `Send` commands `SendInput` due to it being the recommended faster and more reliable send mode<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#SendInputDetail)</sup>.
And then about `{Blind`}. Normally, when you just send something with a send command, it automatically releases any modifiers you may be holding. But if you use the blind send mode<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#Blind)</sup>, this doesn't happen. So <kbd>Shift</kbd> is still held down all the time.

Comment: Thanks 0x464e for the response. However, I tried using the sendInput command and {Blind} but it still didn't work.. Here is my full script:

Comment: There seems to be something missing form that comment? And it seems to work perfectly fine for me :/ https://i.imgur.com/bVpNIip.gif

Comment: Sorry about the comment.. I tried to edit but it said I only had 5 minutes or so.

The behavior of my orginal script was to make using CAPS+J/K/L/I move the cursor without selection to Left/Down/Right/Up consequently.

Upon pressing Alt with The CAPS.. it selects.

Your code is really good, I just can't modify it to make the original ALT behavior when selecting.

Comment: Oh right, my version is the other way around. If at all possible, I'd recommend letting it just be that way. Makes the code a whole lot easier. If not, you have to send alt up.

Comment: Thank you so much for the continous followup  I've been using this script for years now, before Excel, changing it now would be really confusing :)

How do I send alt up to avoid the release of the shift (Alt) key between the key presses?

Comment: Sorry took me a bit to respond. But see the edited version now. Should be all good now.

Comment: Thanks 0x464e.. Can I offer you a job that might take 20 minutes from your time? mnabilsalama at google mail 

Thank you

Comment: Your script works perfectly for the simple right/left/up/down function.. My Original script however remaps CAPS to do lots of functions including pivotal navigation, search, select all, move to end of line, beginning of line, beginning of paragraph, etc..      so is it possible to make your script in a seperate ahk file so it doesn't confuse the other long script and make it only work when xlmain is active and suspends and return to the original script when xlmain is not active?

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean. If it'd be possible to see what kind of stuff you have in your original script, I could see about what could be done to not break the other functionality. And if by google mail you mean the email address gmail com, I've emailed you.

Comment: I used your script and now I have two separate scripts, because having them together with "IfWinActive" and "IfWinNotActive" caused A LOT of disruptions.
But the issue now, I have to keep initiating and exiting the scripts manually every time I activate Excel window or navigate away from it.  Do you think I can have this done automatically when Excel is Active, run this script, Once it's no longer active, exit and run/reload the other script?

Comment: There is no way to do this in AHK?